# Logstash: Pass Field Content to Filter

Tags: filter, logstash

I'm writing a filter and I need to pass a field to it, but I don't know how. I can only specify the name of the field rather than its content:

```
filter {
  if [path] =~ "access" {
    :
    enhance {
      ref => uri  # or "uri", [uri]
    }
  }
}
```

All will set `ref` to the string "uri". The config-line in the filter is

```
  config :ref, :validate => :string, :required => true
```

Of course I can do `event[ref]` in the filter, but passing the content seems more elegant. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to know how to use `ref` in your Ruby code that you've written.  Since you've already defined the

```
config :ref, :validate => :string, :required => true
```

you just use `@ref` to get the value.

For example, `event['somefield'] = @ref`

Comment: Using `@ref` treats `ref` as an instance variable of the filter. I'm not much of a Ruby-coder, but for some reason it doesn't make a difference if I use `@ref` or `ref` in the filter-function. In other words, `ref` and `@ref` contain the string "uri", not the content of the uri-field in the configuration, which basically is what I already have.

Comment: I guess your question is unclear then.  @ref is what you put on the right hand side of ref => in the config file.  If you want to get the field that ref refers to, its just event[@ref]

Comment: If I put `@uri` on the right hand side in the configuration file I get a parsing error as "@" is illegal there. I'm not sure what's unclear about my question. I quoted snippets of the configuration file and the filter. I want to get the content of the field "uri" to the filter rather than the field name.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is `ref => "%{[url]}"`

Comment: Nope, that lets `ref` be that string "%{[url]}". By now I start to believe that it's not possible... :/

Comment: The docs here: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/configuration#sprintf say that you can omit the [] if it's a top level field... so `%{url}` ?